# How to update subdocument array using subdocument id without parent id using nodejs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js, mongoose

Here i like to explain my problem clearly

I need to update subdocument array using subdocument ID wihtout getting Parent ID

> this is my route

```
router.get('/register-list', function(req, res){
        RegisterList.find(function(err, docs){
            res.json(docs);
        });
    });
```

here am getting data from registerList using nodejs.

Using the above route code, here am getting subdocument array data using the below angularjs controller code and display it using ng-repeat.

> this is my angularjs Controller Code

```
$scope.RegisterView = function(id){
        $http.get('/auth/register-list/' + id).success(function(response){
            $scope.bookinglist = response.booking;
        });
    };
```

HTML View

```
    <tr ng-repeat="booking in bookinglist">
                            <td>{{booking.order_id}}</td>
                            <td>{{booking.can_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{booking.can_quantity}}</td>
                            <td>{{booking.can_cost}}</td>
                            <td>{{booking.delivery_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{booking.delivery_timeslot}}</td>
                            <td>{{booking.subscription_type}}</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="RegisterEdit(booking._id)">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="RegisterUpdate(booking._id)" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    </td>

    </tr>
```

Json View:

[image]

> Mongoose Schema:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var registerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            area_name : String,
            warehouse_name : String,
            booking : [{
                order_id : String,
                can_name : String,
                can_quantity : String,
                can_cost : String,
                delivery_date : Date,
                delivery_timeslot : String,
                subscription : String,
                subscription_type : String,
                total_cost : String,
                status: { type: String, default: 'UnderProcess' }, 
                ordered_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
                delivered_at: { type: Date }
            }],
            name: String,
            email : String,
            mobile_no : String,
            password : String,
            otp : String,
            address : [{
                flat_no: String,
                street: String,
                city: String,
            }],
            date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('RegisterList', registerSchema);
```

Help to find out subdocument using subdocument_id and update it using subdocument id wihtout parent ID

Comment: help finding it where? In mongoose or angular? If it's in angular you alreaady seem to have the parent ID so issue is not clear at all

Comment: mongoose aswell as angular, to update speciific booking._id data